# Xamarin forms set popup border radius using Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: xaml, xamarin, popup, nuget, xamarin.forms

I am developing an `IOS` application using `Xamarin.Forms`,in that application I am showing a popup using [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup). I have tried to change the `border radius(Increase)` of the `popup window` but I couldn't achieve it.anyone please help me to accomplish this changes in my app.

**Expected Screen**

[image]

**Actual Screen**

[image]

**Popup.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="TestApp.Popup" 
    xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:TestApp;assembly=TestApp"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        Padding="20, 10, 20, 20" 
        Opacity="0.9">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" 
                >
            <StackLayout Padding="0, 10, 0, 40" >
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="congratsText"
                        Text=""
                        TextColor="#396BA2" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        FontFamily="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"    
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=1}"  
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                        local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"/>              
                    <Label x:Name="callText"
                        TextColor="#396BA2" 
                        FontFamily="MYRIADPRO-REGULAR"
                        FontSize="18"
                            Margin="10"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"    
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=1}"  
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=foundText, Property=Y, Factor=1,Constant=60}"
                        local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="MYRIADPRO-REGULAR" >
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <FormattedString.Spans>
                                    <Span Text="Please call " />
                                    <Span Text="0987654321" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Span Text="for any help." />
                                 </FormattedString.Spans>
                            </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>                            
                    <Button x:Name="OkButton" 
                        BackgroundColor="#9DC96F"
                        FontFamily="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="20"
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" 
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="40"  
                        Text="Ok" 
                        TextColor="White" 
                        Clicked="ok"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=ResendButton, Property=Y, Factor=1,Constant=75}"
                        local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"/>
                    <Button x:Name="LoginButton" 
                        BorderColor="#9DC96F"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        BorderWidth="2"
                        FontFamily="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="20"
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" 
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="40"  
                        Text="Cancel" 
                        TextColor="#9DC96F" 
                        Clicked="Cancel"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=OkButton, Property=Y, Factor=1,Constant=55}"
                        local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="MYRIADPRO-BOLD"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: According to the README for https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup there is no border radius property that can be adjusted for the popup page. Either contact the author of the library and suggest that be added, or download the source and modify it yourself to add border radius setting.

Comment: Thanks @jgoldberger for your suggestion. is there any other `plugin` available for showing a popup along with adjustment of `border radius`?

Comment: You can download sourse code from github and add this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm creator of this plugin. Plugin doesn't support border radius. It is not duty of plugin. Plugin must shows popup page and only. You must make views and styles themselves. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any document about how to use this plugin.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Yes. You can find the documentation on github page

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this successfully by setting the `BackgroundColor` of the outer `StackLayout` to Transparent. Then setting the `CornerRadius` property on the inner `Frame`

Answer (score 2):

Replaces `<Frame BackgroundColor="White">`

With `<Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="40">`